# After I publish new website version, IE 11 / Windows Phone browser say: "This page can’t be displayed", other browsers work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-11

I made a .NET MVC4 application that uses jQuery Mobile. When a user visits the website, it looks for a cookie, so it can retrieve the user information. If it find the cookie, it will store the userprofile in the session, otherwise it will create a new userprofile which will also be stored in the session. If the sessions is not found, it will look for the cookie again or create a new profile. The application is hosted on a Server-Farm of 3 servers.

Now for my problem:

- When I visit the website using my Windows Phone browser / IE11, everything will work. Meanwhile I do the same with my Android browser / Chrome desktop browser, still no problems.
- Then I do a update to the website (update the binaries), which will cause IIS to recycle.
- I hit refresh on the Android browser / Chrome browser, no problem, everything works.
- I hit refresh on the Windows Phone browser / IE11, and it will show: "This page can’t be displayed"

Any of you got any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: Extra info, if i close IE11 and open the site again, it works again. With windows phone browser i need to go to a different website, clean my cache, kill the browser, open it again and goto the website, then it works again.

Comment: It is because IE caches everything, to solve this you could minimise all the css files so it gets a new version when you visit the site this can be done with the webdev tools add in for visual studio. in the options of IE11 go to settings - internet options - general (at the bottom settings) where it says get a new version of the site click everytime i visit the webpage ---- on winphone got no idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was overloading the browser with cookies, IE didn't like that. Fixed the cookies, fixed IE problem.